# Join model not getting created properly using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a User model and a Project model joined with the Ownership model using has_many :through. I am trying to set an Ownership attribute's value as I create an association between a User and a Project by using accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :admin, :projects

  has_many :ownerships
  has_many :projects, :through => :ownerships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects
```

Here is my ownership model:

```
class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :owner_type

  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, :presence => true

  validates :project_id, :presence => true

  validates :owner_type, :presence => true

end
```

and my project model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :description

      has_many :ownerships
      has_many :users, :through => :ownerships
```

and this is how I'm trying to set the owner_type value of the ownership model as its being created:

```
current_user.ownerships.create(:owner_type => 'designer', :project => @project)
```

for some reason this isn't creating the ownership join model or (obviously) setting the owner_type value of the ownership model. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: in your create method, have you tried using `:project_id => @project.id` instead of `:project => @project`

Comment: No, I have not. I am a little confused about how that create works actually. If I pass it :project_id => @project.id, will the ownership model know to join the correct User with the correct Project? Do i need to change anything else to get this to work?

Comment: I'm not sure you can set attributes on a has_many through association like this. But maybe I'm wrong.